# Missing Pixel or Grid Value in the output while Calculating Standard Precipitation Index (SPI) using climate_indices library in Python

Tags: python, netcdf, climate, spi

I am using **NetCDF** **Gridded dataset of IMD Rainfall** ([NetCDF can be downloaded from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/abhilashsinghimd/AASD_Geojson/main/RF_Monthly_India.nc)), for calculating the **Standard Precipitation Index (SPI)**, using [climate_indices](https://pypi.org/project/climate-indices/) library of Python

I have changed all the null values to Zero in the Input file.

still the output is giving **null values**,

even though I have used quite long term data of around 72 years from 1951 to 2022;

```
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import climate_indices
from climate_indices import indices
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# ########### Open Dataset ##########################################
p = xr.open_dataset(r"C:\Climdex\RF_NC\RF_Single\RF_Monthly_India.nc")

da_precip = p.rf

# replace all values equal to -999 with np.nan
da_precip = da_precip.da_precip(monthly['rf'] != -999.0)
# replace all np.nan values equal to 0
da_precip.fillna(0)

da_precip_groupby = da_precip.stack(point=('lat', 'lon')).groupby('point')

# apply SPI to each `point`
scale = 1
distribution = climate_indices.indices.Distribution.gamma
data_start_year = 1951
calibration_year_initial = 1951
calibration_year_final = 2022
periodicity = climate_indices.compute.Periodicity.monthly

da_spi = xr.apply_ufunc(indices.spi,
                        da_precip_groupby,
                        scale,
                        distribution,
                        data_start_year,
                        calibration_year_initial,
                        calibration_year_final,
                        periodicity)

da_spi

# unstack the array back into original dimensions
da_spi = da_spi.unstack('point')
# da_spi

legend_levels = [-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3]
da_spi.sel(time='2015').plot(cmap='RdBu', col='time', col_wrap=4, levels=legend_levels)
```

[image: Missing Values for Pixel]

**How to correct it ?**